# Using real device as simulator & storage

Tags: ios, xcode, nsuserdefaults, userdefaults

I've started to use my own Iphone as a simulator instead of the virtual one.
My testing app uses UserDefaults to save some persistent data.
If I rebuild the app via XCode on my phone this data does not get resetted.
Is there a way to clear the data without de-installing the app and re-installing it via XCode on my phone again?
And without actually adding some extra code.

Comment: You can remove the app from the phone and then install it again via xcode and it will clear any UserDefaults data

Comment: @Scriptable Please read the last sentence of the question (now the next-to-last sentence).

Comment: @Scriptable yeah thats what I am doing currently, but I feel like there has to be a faster/easier way

Comment: So you want to clear user defaults without doing either 1. Delete and reinstall the app or 2. Add code to clear the defaults. There are no other ways to clear user defaults from an app on a device. And in an actual simulator your only other option would be to find the plist file and delete it.

Comment: @rmaddy Seems like the only convenient way for me is to add some code then. I thought about removing the value when applicationWillTerminate is called. Would this work?

Comment: @MarvisCapleton you can reset the device also =D

Comment: `applicationWillTerminate` isn't always called. Better to clear the defaults when the app starts. `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`.

Comment: Yep, that works. Thanks for the assistance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

```
UserDefaults.standard.removePersistentDomain(forName:Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier!)
UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
```

Comment: Better yet would be to wrap it in a `DEBUG` conditional macro so it doesn't get built in release mode

Comment: @MichaelHulet yes he should do this if he want to maintain data between different launches

Comment: `synchronize` is obsolete. Do not call it.

Comment: @rmaddy may be the app crash in this method who know

Comment: I want to do it without modifying the code if possible.

Comment: @Sh_Khan I have no idea how your last comment applies to my comment. Please read the documentation for `UserDefaults synchronize`. It clearly states: *"this method is unnecessary and shouldn't be used."*.

Comment: @rmaddy i mean if the app crashed in the above method without **synchronize**  the delete line is not completely executed

Comment: @Sh_Khan And how is that a problem? This is debug code. Fix the cause of the crash. The next time the app is run the user defaults will be cleared.